# What is the correct way to pass an event handler to a Flatlist render item in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to call an onFocus event handler when a Flatlist item is focused in a TV app. Currently I am passing the function as part of the data object in the data array passed to the Flatlist:

```js
const handleFocus = (event) => {
    focusedItemIndexRef.current = event;
};

const flatListTestData = [...Array(100).keys()].map((x, i) => ({
    data: x,
    id: String(i),
    handleFocus,
}));

...

   const FlatlistRenderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <Interactable
            style={{
                height: 175,
                width: 250,
            }}
            onFocus={() => {
                item.handleFocus(index);
            }}
        >
            <Image source={item.imageSource}>
                <Text>{item.id}</Text>
            </Image>
        </Interactable>
    );
};
```

This works but I feel like passing functions as part of the data prop is wrong, since the functions are not "data", and also I might not be taking advantage of event bubbling with this method. I do not want the render item component to exist inside the Flatlist container component.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your problem, you want to call your `onFocus` event handler when the `FlatList` item is on focus. If I have understood your question correctly, then all you need is [viewabilityConfig](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#viewabilityconfig) and [onViewableItemsChanged](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onviewableitemschanged) which tracks for the item inside the `FlatList` when changes or I must say, when it comes into **focus**.

Implementation can be done like this:

```js
const viewabilityConfig = {
  waitForInteraction: true,
  // At least one of the viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold or itemVisiblePercentThreshold is required.
  viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95,
  itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 75
}

// EDIT --- More enhanced way of finding out which item is in focus
const onViewableItemsChanged = ({viewableItems, changed}) => {
  // You can do whatever you want to do here while checking/observing the items getting changed. For example: Call your onFocus handler
  
  // Call once the scrolling stops, as it sometimes throws **undefined** while scrolling stops, like a milliseconds difference. Best practise and non-faulty approach
  if(viewableItems.length > 0){
    // Get the first viewable item. Supposing you have id in each item
    const firstViewItem = viewableItems[0];
    // Get its index into the items
    const index = yourItemsArrayPassedInDataOfFlatList.findIndex(item => item.id === firstViewItem.id);

    console.info("First View Item", firstViewItem);
    console.info("Changed in this iteration", changed);
  }
};

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
      onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
      data={yourItemsArrayPassedInDataOfFlatList}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alok, but I don't see how I can know which item is in focus by using the `onViewableItemsChanged` callback.

Comment: Your `viewableItems` argument gives the items which you pass in your FlatList for `renderItem`. What does it return btw in your `console.log()` in your `onViewableItemsChanged` @Mr.Robot?

Comment: Yes, in the callback you see a list items that have changed visibility.

Comment: Exactly. So basically, you handle everything in the `onViewableItemsChanged` only @Mr.Robot. Let me know what exactly do you need here, I will try to answer the same.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that I should add logic into the `onViewableItemsChanged` callback to figure out which item is focused based on which items were viewable but are now not after focus changed?

Comment: I have added the logic for finding out the item which is in focus. You can play around with `viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold` in your `viewabilityConfig` object to give what percentage of the item should be visible which should trigger `onViewableItemsChanged`.  Hope that helps @Mr.Robot. And if it did work out for you, please upvote and mark it as correct answer for the other devs' convenience for finding out the correct answer in future :)

Comment: Thanks very much, unfortunately I really don't see this as a solution - viewable items  only have a very loose relationship with what item is focused. Also if you focus from one item to another in the middle of the list, the callback will not be called, because viewable items will not change.

Comment: No problem @Mr.Robot. I hope you will find your solution soon. Do post your answer, if you only find the solution, will be happy to learn something new :)